# Navigation Drawer janks/lags when loading fragment

Tags: android, xml, performance, android-layout

I'm currently trying to improve the performance of my android application. The navigation drawer itself works fine, but when I open any page from the drawer, there are a lot of lags/janks. The fragments basically do http rest requests and display a Google Map or a listview. 
I already tried to enable hardware acceleration, but that did not solve my problem. 
The Screenshot shows an example of such an fragment with enabled GPU rendering profil. 
Is there anything I can do to improve performance? 
Maybe I'm doing all the downloading stuff in the wrong place. (`onStart()`) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTP9s.jpg)

Comment: Do you mean to say there is a lag between when you click on your item in navigation drawer  and your fragment is loaded?

Comment: Exactly, If you take a look at the attached Screenshot you can see a lot of junk at the "beginning" of the fragment lifecycle

Comment: You can try loading the fragment after you close the navigation drawer. Probably by using Handler().postDelayed with 300 milliseconds. Also, downloading is done asynchronously, so it doesn't matter at this moment.